# web.xml intellij is not auto completing when adding servlet or filter

Tags: java, xml, intellij-idea

When i create a servlet or a filter in eclipse the xml code is automatically insert into the web.xml. But when i do the same thing in Intellij i need to manually edit the xml file.

When i type the code below in Intellij i get an error "filter should have mapping" But why is this not automatically created when i use the code below.

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>TestFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>be.demoapp.filters.TestFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
```

There has to be a very simple answer for this but i can't figure out why Intellij does not auto complete the web.xml and eclipse does. Or do i need to turn on some plugin. I can't find a good answer on this ?

*Edit these are the settings in my project
[image]

Comment: Have you added the "Web" facet to your project in the "Project Settings"?

Comment: @SteveC I think i already did this i upload a image to confirm this.

Comment: If you click anywhere in the filter declaration and type <alt><enter> I think it will create the mapping for you. Not having a filter mapping is an error.

Comment: @SteveC  This also does not work. But when i do <f en then type <ctrl><space> i can select filter mapping from a list of possibilities.

Comment: I should have tried it first. Ctrl-N anywhere in the web.xml will pop an option to generate the correct entries for a servlet filter

Comment: @SteveC If i use ctrl-n i get a pop to search classes so this still does not work.

Comment: It's the shortcut for Code/Generate... I don't use Windows so I'm guessing a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Inside your class, use the annotation `@WebFilter(name = "TestFilter", urlPatterns = "/TestFilter")`

It won't show in `web.xml` but it will do the trick.